# Prompt user for list of values in query with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access with a query and asking the user for input (in a list format). If I run the query as follows it works:

```
WHERE var in (1,2,3)
```

But if I'm prompting the user to enter it, it doesn't work (is there another syntax?)

```
WHERE var in ([Enter list:])
```

I'd rather not create a combo box form/list, etc. if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access does not support a parameter as the value list for `IN ()`

In your example, whatever the user supplies for `[Enter list:]` will be interpreted as just one value --- not a list of values.

You could do something like this instead, but it's ugly and probably slow ...

```sql
WHERE Instr(
        1,
        ',' & [Enter list:] & ',',
        ',' & var & ','
        ) > 0
```